# Making dua in your head

Tags: dua

Is it permissible to make dua in one's head? When we're in public for example, we can't speak or whisper our duas. So does it still count if we say it all to ourselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allah SWT is All-Hearer, All-Knower. Whatever (Halal or Haram) we think in our mind, Allah SWT still hears, knows and listens to us.

Answer (score 0):

I do it all the time. Your connection to Allah is just mind-blowing!

وَاذْكُرُوا نِعْمَةَ اللَّهِ عَلَيْكُمْ وَمِيثَاقَهُ الَّذِي وَاثَقَكُم بِهِ إِذْ قُلْتُمْ سَمِعْنَا وَأَطَعْنَا وَاتَّقُوا اللَّهَ إِنَّ اللَّهَ عَلِيمٌ بِذَاتِ الصُّدُورِ

And remember the favor of Allah on you and His covenant with which He bound you firmly when you said: We have heard and we obey and be careful of (your duty to) Allah, surely Allah knows what is in the breasts.

Answer (score 0):

We're expected to live with one foot in this world and the other foot in the other world. This means that we do **not** have to do *dua* all the time - far from. What is obligatory is the five daily *namaz*, and it matters **not** if one says ones *dua* aloud or in one's mind as 'Allah is Knowing, Wise'.